# How to chef search for role with OR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chef-recipe, chef-infra

I want to search nodes with role "mapreduce-datanode" & "mapreduce-namenode".

So i tried following :

```
hadoop_nodes = search(:node, "role:mapreduce-datanode OR role:mapreduce-namenode AND chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment} AND domain:#{node['domain']}")
```

Is this correct way to do ?

Thanks.

Comment: you should group the OR (with () as it has less precedence usually, here you match `role:mapreduce-datanode` or the rest of the conditions. I would use `"(role:mapreduce-datanode OR role:mapreduce-namenode) AND ...` (Warning: not tested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `"mapreduce-datanode" & "mapreduce-namenode"`, as you state, then why are you using an OR?

If you really want an AND, then you want:

```
hadoop_nodes = search(:node, "role:mapreduce-datanode AND role:mapreduce-namenode AND chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment} AND domain:#{node['domain']}")
```

If you want the union of the two sets (ie you really did mean OR) then try this:

```
hadoop_nodes = search(:node, "(role:mapreduce-datanode OR role:mapreduce-namenode) AND chef_environment:#{node.chef_environment} AND domain:#{node['domain']}")
```